# How to create new user defined method for picking date from .csv file as param and automate script through Selenium with Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium4

I need to create a method to read a date from a CSV file as a parameter.

I also need to automate selecting that date from the calendar tool whose HTML is below. I'm using Selenium with Java.

```
<div class="react-datepicker__month" role="listbox" aria-label="month  2022-06">
    <div class="react-datepicker__week">
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--029 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, May 29th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">29</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--030 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Monday, May 30th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">30</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--031 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, May 31st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">31</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--001" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 1st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">1</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--002" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 2nd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">2</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--003" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, June 3rd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">3</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--004 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 4th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-datepicker__week">
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--005 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 5th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">5</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--006 react-datepicker__day--selected react-datepicker__day--today" tabindex="0" aria-label="Choose Monday, June 6th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">6</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--007" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 7th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">7</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--008" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 8th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">8</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--009" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 9th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">9</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--010" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, June 10th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">10</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--011 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 11th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-datepicker__week">
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--012 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 12th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">12</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--013" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Monday, June 13th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">13</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--014" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 14th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">14</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--015" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 15th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">15</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--016" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 16th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">16</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--017" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, June 17th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">17</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--018 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 18th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">18</div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-datepicker__week">
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--019 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 19th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">19</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--020" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Monday, June 20th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">20</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--021" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 21st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">21</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--022" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 22nd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">22</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--023" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 23rd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">23</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--024" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, June 24th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">24</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--025 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 25th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">25</div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-datepicker__week">
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--026 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 26th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">26</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--027" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Monday, June 27th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">27</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--028" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 28th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">28</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--029" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 29th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">29</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--030" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 30th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">30</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--001 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, July 1st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">1</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--002 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, July 2nd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="react-datepicker__week">
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--003 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, July 3rd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">3</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--004 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Monday, July 4th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">4</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--005 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, July 5th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">5</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--006 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, July 6th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">6</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--007 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Thursday, July 7th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">7</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--008 react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, July 8th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">8</div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--009 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, July 9th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading CSV, you use one of these methods: https://www.baeldung.com/java-csv-file-array

Now, given you have the data, you can

1 - Select the month by using the following CSS selector: `div[aria-label="month  " + YEAR + "-" + MONTH]`

2 - And inside the element of the month, you can find the day with the following CSS selector: `div[class^="react-datepicker__day--" + DATE]`

`^=`  indicates you want to look for a partial match in the attribute `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something for you to work with which you can modify as per oyur need and play around:

This is my CSV file:

[image]

This is my Java + Selenium code to get dates from CSV and highlight the particular element in the web page:

```
String line = null;
String day = null;
String month = null;
String year = null;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/var/www/html/1/test.csv"));
br.readLine();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // use comma as separator
    String[] cols = line.split(",");
    String[] split1 = cols[0].split("-");
    day = split1[0];
    month = split1[1];
    year = split1[2];
    System.out.println("Day: " + day + "\tMonth: " + month + "\tYear: " + year);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@aria-label, '" + day + "')]")));

    String[] split2 = cols[1].split("-");
    day = split1[2];
    month = split1[1];
    year = split1[0];
    System.out.println("Day: " + day + "\tMonth: " + month + "\tYear: " + year);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='3px solid red'", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@aria-label, '" + day + "')]")));
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="react-datepicker__month" role="listbox" aria-label="month  2022-06">
        <div class="react-datepicker__week">
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--029 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, May 29th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">29</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--030 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Monday, May 30th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">30</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--031 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, May 31st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">31</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--001" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 1st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">1</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--002" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 2nd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">2</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--003" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Friday, June 3rd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">3</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--004 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 4th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__week">
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--005 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 5th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">5</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--006 react-datepicker__day--selected react-datepicker__day--today"
                tabindex="0" aria-label="Choose Monday, June 6th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">6</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--007" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 7th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">7</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--008" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 8th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">8</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--009" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 9th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">9</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--010" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Friday, June 10th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">10</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--011 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 11th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">11</div>
        </div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__week">
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--012 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 12th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">12</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--013" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Monday, June 13th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">13</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--014" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 14th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">14</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--015" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 15th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">15</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--016" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 16th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">16</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--017" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Friday, June 17th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">17</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--018 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 18th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">18</div>
        </div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__week">
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--019 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 19th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">19</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--020" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Monday, June 20th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">20</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--021" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 21st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">21</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--022" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 22nd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">22</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--023" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 23rd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">23</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--024" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Friday, June 24th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">24</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--025 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Saturday, June 25th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">25</div>
        </div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__week">
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--026 react-datepicker__day--weekend" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Sunday, June 26th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">26</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--027" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Monday, June 27th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">27</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--028" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Tuesday, June 28th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">28</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--029" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Wednesday, June 29th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">29</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--030" tabindex="-1"
                aria-label="Choose Thursday, June 30th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">30</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--001 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, July 1st, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">1</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--002 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, July 2nd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="react-datepicker__week">
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--003 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Sunday, July 3rd, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">3</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--004 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Monday, July 4th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">4</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--005 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Tuesday, July 5th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">5</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--006 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Wednesday, July 6th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">6</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--007 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Thursday, July 7th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">7</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--008 react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Friday, July 8th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">8</div>
            <div class="react-datepicker__day react-datepicker__day--009 react-datepicker__day--weekend react-datepicker__day--outside-month"
                tabindex="-1" aria-label="Choose Saturday, July 9th, 2022" role="option" aria-disabled="false">9</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```